# Integer array lookup using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Let's say I have a table called `tag`:

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  text TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

And I use integer arrays on other tables to reference those tags:

```
CREATE TABLE device (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  tag_ids INTEGER[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',
);
```

What is the simplest and most efficient way that I can map the `tag_ids` to the appropriate rows in `tag` such that I can query the `device` table and the results will include a `tags` column with the `text` of each tag in a text array?

I understand that this is not the preferred technique and has a number of significant disadvantages. I understand that there is no way to enforce referential integrity in arrays. I understand that a many-to-many join would be much simpler and probably better way to implement tagging.

The database normalization lectures aside, is there a graceful way to do this in postgres?  Would it make sense to write a function to accomplish this?

Comment: You want `intarray` with its gin and gist index implementations for arrays of integer and the contains tests `<@`, `@>`.

Comment: @CraigRinger- Currently I am declaring it as `INTEGER[]` then manually creating the appropriate `GIN` index- is it better to specifically use the `intarray` module?

Comment: `intarray` provides index opclasses that are more efficient IIRC. Also, if you insert rows much you're going to be better off with GiST than GIN.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but IIRC:

```
SELECT 
    device.*, t."text"
FROM 
    device d
    left outer join tag t on ( ARRAY[t.id] @> d.tag_ids)
```

should be able to use a GiST or GIN index on `d.tag_ids`. That's also useful for queries where you want to say "find rows containing tag [x]".

I might've got the direction of the `@>` operator wrong, I always get it muddled. See the array operators docs for details.

The intarray module provides a gist opclass for arrays of integer which I'd recommend using; it's more compact and faster to update.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a combination of `unnest` and `join` for this.

i.e. something of the form:

```
select unnest(t.tag_ids) as tag_id, d.*
from device as d
join tag as t ON (d.tag_id = d.id)
order by d.tag_id;
```